# CSS - Animated button

Tags: html, css

I need animated CSS button, something like on the picture,
You can find that buttons here: http://todomvc.com/

Something similar to this:
[image: Animated CSS buttons.]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Them some fancy buttons..

Comment: Just classic animated button http://scratchpad.io/fierce-frogs-2484

Answer (score 2):

You could try placing a div inside the button like so:

```
<button>
    <div>
        Button
    </div>
</button>
```

And then set the div to animate to `width: 100%` and `background: red`

For the red line underneath, maybe an animation where you set the `border-bottom` property